# Can I improve the code used in a MVC view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I wrote an class that I call in an MVC view. But the call uses 2 lines. I want to make it only one line. In general, I want to make the code just better / more elegantly even though it works.

The class checks if the logged in user is part of a role and if this role has certain Identity claims. Based on that, it will show a menu option in the _Layout.

I have the following class I call from my _layout view:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using StudentUnion0105.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;    

namespace StudentUnion0105.Classes
{
    public class ShowMenu

    {
        public async Task<bool> ShowMenuBasedOnClaim(System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal User,
            string ClaimType, string ClaimValue,
            UserManager<SuUser> userManager
            , RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
        {

            var CurrentUser = await userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
            var roles = await userManager.GetRolesAsync(CurrentUser);
            foreach (var rolename in roles)
            {
                var role = await roleManager.FindByNameAsync(rolename);
                var claims = await roleManager.GetClaimsAsync(role);
                foreach (var claim in claims)
                {
                    if (claim.Type == ClaimType && claim.Value == ClaimValue)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }

            }
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

The following 2 pieces are from my _Laout.cshtml. The first one is the top.

```
@inject SignInManager<SuUser> signInManager
@inject UserManager<SuUser> userManager
@inject RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager
```

The second one is where I call the class

```
 @{var show = new StudentUnion0105.Classes.ShowMenu();
      if (await show.ShowMenuBasedOnClaim(User, "Menu", "Roles", userManager, roleManager))
      {
         <a asp-controller="Administration" asp-action="RoleList" class="dropdown-item">Roles</a>
      }
}
```

The two lines I want to make nicer are in the _Layout:

```
@{var show = new StudentUnion0105.Classes.ShowMenu();
      if (await show.ShowMenuBasedOnClaim(User, "Menu", "Roles", userManager, roleManager))
```

But any suggestion to improve this (even though it works) would be great.

Comment: Which 2 lines ?

Comment: Added more in the description: the lines are: 

@{var show = new StudentUnion0105.Classes.ShowMenu();

      if (await show.ShowMenuBasedOnClaim(User, "Menu", "Roles", userManager, roleManager))

Comment: Combining more logic into 1 line rarely improves readability. Often the opposite is the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to me, this seems pretty minimal.  Correct me if I am wrong, but your two steps are:

1. Construct an instance of ShowMenu
2. Then use one of its methods, ShowMenuBasedOnClaim(), in a conditional statement.

Honestly, I think it would just muddle the meaning by trying to combine these two statements into one line.  Readability, is surely more important than consolidation of the lines.  If you want to make your code more elegant, maybe add some informative comments.

Comment: @PeterleGrand No problem.  If you'd like to improve your code's readability, you can try to format the ShowMenu class' body.  Also, I believe, you can remove surrounding brackets from single line if-statements.  Sometimes reducing the number of grouping symbols can help readability.  Have you even used a feature like "beautify code"?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Good one. Don't know about the feature of "Beautify code". I only  once and a while use CTL+K CTL+D.